# Is it possible to create a Couchbase view that groups output without a reduce function?

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

In Couchbase or CouchDB, is it possible to group without an explicit reduce function? In my client code, I want the data to be given to me just as a reduce would receive it (assuming all mappers were used as input, even during a rereduce).  Using `group=true` without a defined reduce function gives me the error:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8092/default/_design/testing1/_view/all?group=true
{"error":"query_parse_error",
 "reason":"Invalid URL parameter 'group' or 'group_level' for non-reduce view."}
```

I can add the identity reduce function:

```
reduce(keys,data) {return data;}
```

but Couchbase complains that I'm not actually reducing anything:

```
{"rows":[], "errors":[
    {"from":"local","reason":"{<<"reduce_overflow_error">>,
        <<"Reduce output must shrink more rapidly: Current output: '...'
    }]}
```

I'd sure like to get the complete reduction in my client.

Comment: Wouldn't that just return the same data as the view with no reduce function? Or are you trying to combine all the data for the same key into a single value?

Comment: Yes, I'd like the view without a reduce, but grouped together by key. The map function yields {attribute : key} pairs, which I'd like to be grouped together on the attribute:

{attr1 : [key1, key2, key3],
 attr2 : [key4, key5]}

Answer (score 1):

This not a technological limitation, it's a logical limitation.  You cannot logically group results without some reduction of those results.  This is analogous to the `GROUP BY` in SQL, you can't use that unless you also have some sort of aggregate function in your SQL query.

Comment: But I can do an "identity reduce" as I mentioned, whose analogue doesn't exist in SQL.  While I understand Couchbase is trying to keep me in the realm of high performance queries, the limitation seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the "identity reduce" is a common pitfall in Couch-style map reduce. The Couch reduce system is designed for reduce functions that look more like:

```
function(keys, values) {
   return values.length;
}
```

The identity reduce will end up storing multiple copies of the map rows, in a non-indexed data structure.

It sounds like what you want is the unique set of keys, regardless of the reduction value. In that case, I would use the _count reduce function, since it is efficient and can run on any underlying data.